# Multiple cursors skipping lines

Tags: multiple-cursors

I have some code that has names every few lines and wanted to use multiple cursors to edit all of them at once but it seems like it will only edit consecutive lines. By this I mean I have code on lines `1 5 11 and 15` I want to edit but with MC I can only seem to grab lines that are one below or above an already marked one. Is there a way to skip multiple lines?

Comment: How about the `mc/add-cursor-on-click` option mentioned in the `README.md` of the repository?  "*Bind to a mouse event to add cursors by clicking. See tips-section.*"  https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el

Comment: I tried that and am getting the message that it must be bound to an event with parameters and am not sure what that means. I am a bit new to Emacs so I am not sure if this is Emacs lingo or mc lingo.

Comment: Use `M-x occur`, to show only the lines you want to work on. In the occur buffer use anything you want to act on the lines.

Comment: @user29896 Did you use the mouse button bindings for `mc/add-cursor-on-click` ?  You can't call it with `M-x`, as it uses the mouse event parameters.

Comment: @Drew thank you for that tip, I had no clue that existed. @phils Thank you for that. I honestly had never seen `mouse-1` before so I was confused on what that was yesterday and it was the end of the work day so I didn't bother looking it up. Thank you for the information and help though, I finally got it working. Also, if you would like to respond to the post with an answer I can mark it correct.